# If I run Java RCP application, I'm getting "java.lang.ClassCastException"

Tags: java

I only have below error logs:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem cannot be cast to org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionSetContributionItem
    at com.yantra.yfc.rcp.common.utils.YRCCommonUtils.handleLogoutActionPermission(YRCCommonUtils.java:38)
    at com.yantra.yfc.rcp.common.utils.YRCCommonUtils.localizeMenuItems(YRCCommonUtils.java:26)
    at com.yantra.yfc.rcp.common.utils.YRCCommonUtils.localizeMenuItems(YRCCommonUtils.java:30)
    at com.yantra.yfc.rcp.common.utils.YRCCommonUtils.localizeMenuItems(YRCCommonUtils.java:30)
    at com.yantra.yfc.rcp.foundation.containers.store.YRCStoreWorkbenchAdvisor.createMenuBar(YRCStoreWorkbenchAdvisor.java:130)
    at com.yantra.yfc.rcp.YRCDesktopWorkbenchAdvisor.postWindowOpen(YRCDesktopWorkbenchAdvisor.java:96)
    at com.yantra.yfc.rcp.foundation.containers.store.YRCStoreWorkbenchAdvisor.postWindowOpen(YRCStoreWorkbenchAdvisor.java:113)
    at com.yantra.yfc.rcp.YRCDesktopWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.postWindowOpen(YRCDesktopWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.fireWindowOpened(WorkbenchWindow.java:1128)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.open(WorkbenchWindow.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.busyOpenWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.doOpenFirstTimeWindow(Workbench.java:1437)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.openFirstTimeWindow(Workbench.java:1388)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchConfigurer.openFirstTimeWindow(WorkbenchConfigurer.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:708)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.init(Workbench.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:1847)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.yantra.yfc.rcp.YRCApplication.run(YRCApplication.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)
!Thread: main : 2016-05-19 17:40:50.71 :
```

Comment: org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem is not instance of org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionSetContributionItem so what else would you expect? I think you need to show us some code that you have that invokes this error.

Comment: This is the old code, which was working earlier. Today, I configured the same code in different work space, and its failing. I'm not sure, but I am thinking it is related to a Java version issue, if anybody faced this issue, earlier please let me know.